# How can I check for the query depth limit without having the introspection

Tags: graphql

I want to check for the depth limit, if implemented, on a GraphQL endpoint. I am looking for a (kind of) universal way to check, without having to find a specific query with a huge depth.

Answer (score -2):

Simple approach is to validate the length of the query string(1000 chars may be). For more generalized and clean solution, you can try the below snippet referred from apollo docs and [graphql-depth-limit](https://github.com/stems/graphql-depth-limit#readme) package.

```
import depthLimit from 'graphql-depth-limit'

app.use('/api', graphqlServer({
  validationRules: [depthLimit(10)]
}));
```

For more details you can check [apollo blog](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/graphql/security/securing-your-graphql-api-from-malicious-queries/) or [howtographql blog](https://www.howtographql.com/advanced/4-security/)

Comment: graphql-depth-limit doesn't appear to exist anymore